# Traversing and accessing views in backbone marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Backbone newb here.

I have a view that extends Backbone.Marionette.Layout and has several regions. Some of these regions have several regions of their own and so on. If I am at the "top level" region, what is the best why to access methods of a child region/view?

I see that I can do something like this:

```
region1.currentView.region2.currentView.region3.method()
```

but that doesn't seem like a good idea. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. You will want to use the event aggregator that is in the Marionette Application class to decouple your application.  I use the following method to communicate across my application.

```
app.vent.trigger('App:Core', { 'caller': 'LoginScreen' });
```

then inside another part of my application I am listening for this event.

```
App.vent.on('App:Core', function (data) {.....
```